# Emacs Orgmode + Terminal = Tab not working

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal

I'm new to emacs + orgmode and I was trying to use it on Mac's terminal. However, when I open an orgmode file on terminal I can't use the tab key to hide/unhide the texts under `*,**,***,...`.

**Question:** is orgmode fully functional **only** on Emacs with the visual interface?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What do you get when you type `C-h k TAB` in terminal emacs (that is: `CTRL` plus `h` followed by `k` followed by `TAB`)?

Comment: On terminal it returns: `TAB runs the command indent-for-tab-command`. On the visual interface I get:  `<tab> runs the command org-cycle`

Comment: Does everything else work in org-mode in the terminal? What do you get for `C-h v major-mode` ?

Comment: I get `major-mode is a variable  defined in ...`. It seems to be normal, but orgmode appears to not work somehow.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: what is the value of the variable `major-mode`?

Comment: I also have this issue. `C-h k TAB` gives `TAB runs...` `...it is bound to TAB...`, `major-mode` is `org-mode`. Most things work, e.g., code execution etc. It is just the tab character not working. `C-i` does not work either. Both `TAB` or `C-i` autocomplete in bash etc., i.e., are registered by the shell